# How to implement pagination in React JS with REST API

Tags: reactjs, rest

I need to create pagination in my site. I'm getting data like this from REST API:

```
{
    "count": 4,
    "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/software/?p=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "category": {
                "id": 10,
                "parent": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Name",
                    "slug": "Slug",
                    "img": "Image"
                },
                "name": "Name",
                "slug": null,
                "img": ""
            },
            "title": "Title",
            "content": "Content",
            "image": "Image",
            "pub_date": "2022-02-02",
            "counter": 0,
            "file": "File",
            "in_archive": false
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "category": {
                "id": 11,
                "parent": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Name",
                    "slug": "Slug",
                    "img": "Image"
                },
                "name": "Name",
                "slug": null,
                "img": ""
            },
            "title": "Title",
            "content": "Content",
            "image": "Image",
            "pub_date": "2022-02-02",
            "counter": 0,
            "file": "File",
            "in_archive": false
        }
    ]
}
```

In React I'm trying to get the data like this:

```
const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
const [count, setCount] = useState(null);
const [nextPage, setNextPage] = useState(null);
const [previousPage, setPreviousPage] = useState(null);
const [valid, setValid] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/software/?p=${currentPage}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        setCount(data.count);
        setNextPage(data.next);
        setPreviousPage(data.previous);
        setValid(true);
      })
}, []);
```

But I have no idea how it must be and how to use it in React Component, I've not done that before.

How it has to be in React?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently your useEffect hook has no dependency. It will only run on mount and unmount. Instead add your currentPage as a dependency for your useEffect Hook.

Whenever the currentPage changes useEffect hook will run and the data will be fetched.

```
useEffect(() => {
          fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/software/?p=${currentPage}`)
              .then(response => response.json())
              .then(data => {
                setCount(data.count);
                setNextPage(data.next);
                setPreviousPage(data.previous);
                setValid(true);
              })
        }, [currentPage]); //Added Dependency
```

To load the next page simply increment your currentPage

```
const incrementPageNumber = () => setCurrentPage(prevPage => prevPage + 1);
```

To load the previous page simply decrement your currentPage

```
const decrementPageNumber = () => {
  if(currentPage <= 1) return; 
  setCurrentPage(prevPage => prevPage - 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, it helped. But I have a question: do I need to add Route with the page number or not?

Comment: For this approach, there is no need for any additional routes

Comment: I have written a small sandbox for you. Refer - https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-meninsky-1i50j?file=/src/App.tsx